# Number of lines in csv.DictReader

Tags: python, iterator, python-3.x

I have a csv DictReader object (using Python 3.1), but I would like to know the number of lines/rows contained in the reader **before** I iterate through it.  Something like as follows...

```
myreader = csv.DictReader(open('myFile.csv', newline=''))

totalrows = ?

rowcount = 0
for row in myreader:
    rowcount +=1
    print("Row %d/%d" % (rowcount,totalrows))
```

I know I could get the total by iterating through the reader, but then I couldn't run the 'for' loop.  I could iterate through a copy of the reader, but I cannot find how to copy an iterator.

I could also use

```
totalrows = len(open('myFile.csv').readlines())
```

but that seems an unnecessary re-opening of the file.  I would rather get the count from the DictReader if possible.

Any help would be appreciated.

Alan

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
rows = list(myreader)
totalrows = len(rows)
for i, row in enumerate(rows):
    print("Row %d/%d" % (i+1, totalrows))
```

Comment: Nice solution - I'm quite new to the idea of iterators, so I hadn't really appreciated enumerate() until now.  Regards.

Comment: Just be careful with your data set size here.  Turning your reader into a list could take GOBS of memory.

Comment: This will load all data into memory, count lines -1 is much nice solutions

Answer (score 23):

You only need to open the file once:

```
import csv

f = open('myFile.csv', 'rb')

countrdr = csv.DictReader(f)
totalrows = 0
for row in countrdr:
  totalrows += 1

f.seek(0)  # You may not have to do this, I didn't check to see if DictReader did

myreader = csv.DictReader(f)
for row in myreader:
  do_work
```

No matter what you do you have to make two passes (well, if your records are a fixed length - which is unlikely - you could just get the file size and divide, but lets presume that isn't the case).  Opening the file again really doesn't cost you much, but you can avoid it as illustrated here.  Converting to a list just to use `len()` is potentially going to waste tons of memory, and not be any faster.

Note: The 'Pythonic' way is to use `enumerate` instead of `+=`, but the `UNPACK_TUPLE` opcode is so expensive that it makes `enumerate` slower than incrementing a local.  That being said, it's likely an unnecessary micro-optimization that you should probably avoid.

More Notes:  If you really just want to generate some kind of progress indicator, it doesn't necessarily have to be record based.  You can `tell()` on the file object in the loop and just report what % of the data you're through.  It'll be a little uneven, but chances are on any file that's large enough to warrant a progress bar the deviation on record length will be lost in the noise.

Comment: Nick - thanks for the reply.  Looks like my avoidance of re-opening the file is not worth the extra code involved (readability comes above performance in this case).  Thanks for the tip regarding enumerate() speed.  Tell() is also new to me - I'll look into it further.  Regards.

Comment: Only problem with this.. what if your using a steam.

Comment: @Nick: There is no magic in the world - this isn't a problem, just a fact.

Comment: DictReader doesn't go back to the start after you iterate through, but since it uses the first row for headers if you don't specify them, you need to skip it after you reset with `seek(0)` : `countrdr.next()`

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2890569/8056572 you can get the number of lines by taking the length of the reader converted to a list. However, this will have an impact on the RAM consumption and you will loose the benefits of the reader (which is a generator).

The best solution in my opinion is to open the file 2 times:

1. count the number of lines:

```py
total_rows = sum(1 for _ in open('myFile.csv')) # -1 if you want to remove the header from the count
```

Note: I am not using `.readlines()` to avoid to load all the lines in memory

2. iterate over the lines

---

According to your snippet you will have something like this:

```py
import csv

totalrows = sum(1 for _ in open('myFile.csv'))

myreader = csv.DictReader(open('myFile.csv'))

for i, _ in enumerate(myreader, start=1):
    print("Row %d/%d" % (i, totalrows))
```

Note: the `start=1` in the `enumerate` indicates the first value of i. By default it is 0, if you keep this default value you have to use `i + 1` in the print statement

---

If you really do not want to open the file two times you can use `seek` as mentioned in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2891061/8056572

```py
import csv

f = open('myFile.csv')

total_rows = sum(1 for _ in f)

f.seek(0)

myreader = csv.DictReader(f)

for i, _ in enumerate(myreader, start=1):
    print("Row %d/%d" % (i, totalrows))
```

Answer (score 2):

> I cannot find how to copy an
>   iterator.

Closest is [itertools.tee](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools.tee#itertools.tee), but simply making a `list` of it, as @J.F.Sebastian suggests, is best here, as itertools.tee's docs explain:

> This itertool may require significant
>   auxiliary storage (depending on how
>   much temporary data needs to be
>   stored). In general, if one iterator
>   uses most or all of the data before
>   another iterator starts, it is faster
>   to use `list()` instead of `tee()`.

Comment: You still have the potentially massive resource consumption with either method.

Comment: Thanks Alex - list it is then.