# how to chunk a csv (dict)reader object in python 3.2?

Tags: csv, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-itertools, chunking

I try to use Pool from the multiprocessing module to speed up reading in large csv files. For this, I adapted an [example](https://networkx.lanl.gov/trac/attachment/ticket/594/betweenness_centrality.py) (from py2k), but it seems like the csv.dictreader object has no length. Does it mean I can only iterate over it? Is there a way to chunk it still?

These questions seemed relevant, but did not really answer my question:
[Number of lines in csv.DictReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890549/number-of-lines-in-csv-dictreader),
[How to chunk a list in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5850536/how-to-chunk-a-list-in-python-3)

My code tried to do this:

```
source = open('/scratch/data.txt','r')
def csv2nodes(r):
    strptime = time.strptime
    mktime = time.mktime
    l = []
    ppl = set()
    for row in r:
        cell = int(row['cell'])
        id = int(row['seq_ei'])
        st = mktime(strptime(row['dat_deb_occupation'],'%d/%m/%Y'))
        ed = mktime(strptime(row['dat_fin_occupation'],'%d/%m/%Y'))
        # collect list
        l.append([(id,cell,{1:st,2: ed})])
        # collect separate sets
        ppl.add(id)
    return (l,ppl)


def csv2graph(source):
    r = csv.DictReader(source,delimiter=',')
    MG=nx.MultiGraph()
    l = []
    ppl = set()
    # Remember that I use integers for edge attributes, to save space! Dic above.
    # start: 1
    # end: 2
    p = Pool(processes=4)
    node_divisor = len(p._pool)*4
    node_chunks = list(chunks(r,int(len(r)/int(node_divisor))))
    num_chunks = len(node_chunks)
    pedgelists = p.map(csv2nodes,
                       zip(node_chunks))
    ll = []
    for l in pedgelists:
        ll.append(l[0])
        ppl.update(l[1])
    MG.add_edges_from(ll)
    return (MG,ppl)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`csv.DictReader` documentation](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7.2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) (and the `csv.reader` class it subclasses), the class returns an iterator. The code should have thrown a `TypeError` when you called `len()`.

You can still chunk the data, but you'll have to read it entirely into memory. If you're concerned about memory you can switch from `csv.DictReader` to `csv.reader` and skip the overhead of the dictionaries `csv.DictReader` creates. To improve readability in `csv2nodes()`, you can assign constants to address each field's index:

```
CELL = 0
SEQ_EI = 1
DAT_DEB_OCCUPATION = 4
DAT_FIN_OCCUPATION = 5
```

I also recommend using a different variable than `id`, since that's a built-in function name.