# How can I get the row count of a CSV file?

Tags: python, csv, count, row

```
fieldnames = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'address']
with open('names.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    for row in reader:
        print(row['first_name'], "'s number", row['last_name'], "address", row['adres'])
```

This is my code to print my CSV file. If the CSV file is empty, I want to print that it's empty. I thought that if i can get the row count of the file, I can check if it's empty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Number of lines in csv.DictReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890549/number-of-lines-in-csv-dictreader)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

just do

```
len(list(reader))
```

it iterates through the `reader` object to create a list, then computes length & the number or rows is the list length (title not included)

note that this statement consumes the file, so store the `list(reader)` variable somewhere if you plan to parse the file.

Comment: In practice, I had to open file once to get row count, close it, open again and parse it normally.

Comment: Yes it works, but it's much better to read the file once and store it in memory (unless the file is super huge and doesn't hold in memory)

Answer (score 10):

An efficient way to get row count using `sum` function(with a *generator expression*):

```
with open('names.csv') as csvfile:
    row_count = sum(1 for row in csvfile)
    print(row_count if row_count else 'Empty')
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this :

```
import os
os.stat("names.csv").st_size == 0
```

Return true if it's empty, you want this right?

Comment: if there's only a title line, that would fail.

Answer (score 0):

You could also enumerate the entries as you parse the file as follows:

```
fieldnames = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'address']

with open('names.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    for count, row in enumerate(reader):
        print(row['first_name'], "'s number", row['last_name'], "address", row['address'])            

    if count == 0:
        print("empty")
```