# Python Polars: How to get the row count of a DataFrame?

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

The CSV file I have is 70 Gb in size. I want to load the DF and count the number of rows, in lazy mode. What's the best way to do so?

As far as I can tell, there is no function like shape in lazy mode according to the documentation.
I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41553467/how-can-i-get-the-row-count-of-a-csv-file) which provide a solution not based on Polars, but I wonder if it is possible to do this in Polars as well.

Comment: What have you found when you did a websearch for "polars get row count lazy"? Was anything applicable to your case? If not, why did it not work?

Comment: why do you need a "polars-based" solution? You're IO-bound here in terms of performance (no computationally intensive operation) so I'd doubt you'll get any benefit from using Rust-based code... at least I'd try to measure first if this is a performance bottle-neck.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke  Websearch for "polars get row count lazy" does not yield relevant result.

Comment: @FObersteiner  The answer I attached to the original post provided a solution. I ask out of curiosity. I have updated the post to clarify this. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: Does this not help? https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/lazyframe/api/polars.LazyFrame.with_row_count.html

Comment: Thanks @SaaruLindestøkke for your response, but Dean MacGregor's suggestion fits my requirements more closely. Unfortunately, with_row_count adds a column to the DF, which was not my intention, and there were performance concerns with this approach

Comment: If that's the right answer for you then please hit the check mark

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### For polars 0.20.5+

To get the row count using polars.

First load it into a lazyframe...

```
lzdf=pl.scan_csv("mybigfile.csv")
```

Then count the rows and return the result

```
lzdf.select(pl.len()).collect()
```

If you just want a python scalar rather than a table as a result then just subset it

```
lzdf.select(pl.len()).collect().item()
```

### For older versions

To get the row count using polars.

First load it into a lazyframe...

```
lzdf=pl.scan_csv("mybigfile.csv")
```

Then count the rows and return the result

```
lzdf.select(pl.count()).collect()
```

If you just want a python scalar rather than a table as a result then just subset it

```
lzdf.select(pl.count()).collect().item()
```

Comment: You can use [`.item()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.item.html) instead of `[0, 0]` (if you're not already aware)

Comment: Note that as of [polars release 0.20.5](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/releases/tag/py-0.20.5) `pl.count()` is deprecated in favour of `pl.len()`. Hence, the answer becomes `lzdf.select(pl.len()).collect().item()`.

Answer (score 2):

Polars dataframe class doesn't have `collect()` method. For normal dataframes (non lazy dataframes), We could
use pl.count and get the result as below .

```py
import polars as pl
df = pl.DataFrame({"a": [1, 8, 3], "b": [4, 5, 2], "c": ["foo", "bar", "foo"]})

row_count = df.select(pl.count())[0,0]

or 

row_count = df.select(pl.count()).item()
```

Comment: Currently accepted answer uses `lzdf` to hint that lazy dataframe is used. Collect is necessary for lazy dfs, but not 'normal' dfs