# Row count expression in Polars?

Tags: python, python-polars

Is there something like `row_number`, or a `row_count` expression in Polars?
Something like the Polars `with_row_index` as an expression, but not just as a data frame method.

I want to rank a given customer's order number in a day using the `over` window function, but can't come up with a solution so far.
`pl.count().over('ID Client'))` gives me the total number of interactions that day. Now I want to have them ordered...
In SQL I believe this works simply with the `RANK()` or `ROW_NUMBER()` window functions.

Can anyone help with it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Polars: How to get the row count of a DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75523498/python-polars-how-to-get-the-row-count-of-a-dataframe)

Comment: @MrIrrelevant This question differs in the sense, that the row number is requested as part of an expression. The linked questions refers to the *total* row count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be searching for [`pl.int_range`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.int_range.html), potentially combined with [`pl.Expr.over`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.over.html).

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "group": ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C"],
})

df.with_columns(pl.int_range(pl.len()).over("group").alias("index"))
```

```
shape: (6, 2)
┌───────┬───────┐
│ group ┆ index │
│ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ str   ┆ i64   │
╞═══════╪═══════╡
│ A     ┆ 0     │
│ A     ┆ 1     │
│ A     ┆ 2     │
│ B     ┆ 0     │
│ B     ┆ 1     │
│ C     ┆ 0     │
└───────┴───────┘
```