# How to print number of data records with csv.dictreader?

Tags: python

Confused, need to "Write your code to print out the number of data records" - i know how to do this in pandas but not csv.DictReader

Have tried solutions from [Number of lines in csv.DictReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890549/number-of-lines-in-csv-dictreader) and with len() with no success.

Comment: Show your code, [mre], and explain what exactly is not as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Do you looking for to do this ?

```
sample.csv
"one","two","three"
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

```
import csv

with open("sample.csv") as f:
    r = csv.DictReader(f)

    print(len(list(r)))

output: 2
```

Comment: I'm here, 

import numpy as np

DATA_FILE = "owid-covid-data.csv"

input_file = csv.DictReader(open(DATA_FILE))
fieldnames = input_file.fieldnames
data_dict = {fn: [] for fn in fieldnames}
print(data_dict.keys())
for line in input_file:
    for k, v in line.items():
        if (v == ''):
             v=0
        try:
            data_dict[k].append(int(v))
        except ValueError:
            try:
                data_dict[k].append(float(v))
            except ValueError:
                data_dict[k].append(v)

Comment: i've tried, 

`

print(len(list(input_file))) but it produced an output of 0

Comment: i am testing how to use the `code` function but it doesn't seem to be working, apologies for the text heavy explainer - just learning stackoverflow

Comment: I retrieve the csv file "owid-covid-data.csv" and get some rows.

```import csv
 
DATA_FILE = "owid-covid-data.csv" 
input_file = csv.DictReader(open(DATA_FILE)) 
print(len(list(input_file)))```

output: 28 # The number of rows in the CSV file.

What do you want exactly ?